# Cancel XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

Good day there

I have a site where I have lots of 'tooltips'. These tooltips are created when hovered on a certain part of text. The tooltip is a div block which appears on top all the other content on site, and is removed when the cursor is moved away from the text. Now, this tooltip is spawned only when the text has `<a rel>` with 'tooltip' class. The tooltip fetches data from MySQL database with XMLHttpRequest and with the rel tag. This all works very well but I have a one little problem. Tooltip.php, which is the main script for fetching data from MySQL (8,809 lines), sometimes takes a while to respond. For example if I just quickly move my cursor through the site and the cursor accidently hovered for 0.05 secs a text with `<a rel>` text, it will generate a tooltip even if my cursor is not any longer on the text. I want some sort of check to check is the cursor still on the same `<a rel>` text, before creating the actual tooltip.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" rel="1" onmouseover="createTooltip(event);" onmousemove="moveTooltip(event);" onmouseout="removeTooltip();" class="tooltip">A tooltip</a>
```

Javascript:

```
   function createTooltip(event)
   {
      var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
      var str = target.rel || target.parentNode.rel; 
      if (str === "" || !str)
      {  
         return;
      }

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else // for older IE clients
      {
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
            var link = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip');
            var oldTooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('object-tooltip'); // removing possible old tooltips...
            for (var k = 0; k < oldTooltip.length; k++)
            {
               if (oldTooltip[k])
               {
                  oldTooltip[k].remove();
               }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++)
            {
               if (str == link[i].rel)
               {
                  var tooltip = document.createElement("div");
                  tooltip.setAttribute('class', 'object-tooltip');
                  tooltip.style.border = "solid 1px black";
                  tooltip.style.color = "white"; //"#99CC00";
                  tooltip.style.position = "fixed";
                  tooltip.style.width = "300px";
                  tooltip.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
                  tooltip.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
                  tooltip.style.padding = "5px 10px 5px 10px";
                  tooltip.style.margin = "-25px 0 0 60px";
                  tooltip.style.backgroundColor = "#0E0E0F";
                  tooltip.style.opacity = "0.9";
                  tooltip.style.display = "inline-block";
                  tooltip.style.zIndex = "100000";
                  tooltip.style.textDecoration = "none";
                  tooltip.style.textAlign = "left";
                  tooltip.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

                  link[i].parentNode.insertBefore(tooltip, link[i].nextSibling);
               }  
            }
         }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "./armory/tooltip.php?s="+str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }

   function moveTooltip(event)
   {
      var tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('object-tooltip');
      for (var i = 0; i < tooltip.length; i++)
      {
         tooltip[i].style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
         tooltip[i].style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
      }
   }

   function removeTooltip()
   {
      var tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('object-tooltip'); // you can have only one tooltip active at time
      for (var i = 0; i < tooltip.length; i++)
      {
         tooltip[i].remove();
      }
   }
```

I will not share tooltip.php for the sake of your time. It only gets the rel attribute and searches MySQL database with the attribute and prints data back. Is it possible to check is the cursor still on the same text, before creating the tooltip?

The best regards

Comment: Rather wait a few (milli)seconds before *starting* the ajax request the check whether you need it, instead of cancelling it when you realize that you don't need it.

Comment: I’m not sure if canceling the request is the best way to go about it – I’d maybe let it go through anyway and just not display the tooltip if the user moved the mouse away again – at least then the value is available immediately next time the user hovers the item. (Assuming you are at least storing the values for tooltips that where retrieved before already, and don’t do a request every time.)

Comment: Good point. The data is stored, yes. But I rather personally would just abort the request. The tooltip.php has 8,809 lines and it has also douzens mysqli queries so in my opinion its better to abort it. But please share your opinions, I am open for suggestions :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welp, based on your current code, you need to add, for instance, a variable outside of the scope of your existing createTooltip function to bind the xhr request to, let's call it, `xmlhttp` to be aligned with your existing code

```
var xmlhttp; //not in a function
```

Now add an event listener for the mouseout function on the `.tooltip` class, then abort the xhr request.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    xmlhttp.abort();
});
```

Now when the element with `.tooltip` triggers the `mouseleave` needless xmlhttprequests will be aborted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Somehow, I can't get addEventListeners work with XMLHttpRequest. But I added instead the abort in removeTooltip (which is called on mouseout), declared xmlhttp outside createTooltip() and it works now fine. Thanks mate, accepted your answer :-)

Comment: @user2966641 Glad this gave you the direction you need.